# Work with JSON Format

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Small task, tried so much I am not able to do this.

```
export class EmployeeDetails {
        employee_id: number,
        employee_name: string,
        employee_startDate: string,
        employee_endDate: string,
        employee_startTime: string,
        employee_endTime: string,
        employee_city: string,
        employee_country: string,
        employee_phone: number,
        employee_email: string

    }

queryResponse = [
{ 
    startDate: '01/01/2001’, 
    endDate: '02/02/2002’ , 
    personDetails : [ 
     { id: 1, name: ‘mounika’, timeDetails: [{ startTime: ’9:00am’, endTime: ’4:00pm’, email: ‘mounika@gmail.com’, phone: ’9232323223’}, { startTime: ’10:00am’, endTime: ’5:00pm’, email: ‘mounika@gmail.com’, phone: ’9232323223’ }]}, 
     { id: 2, name: ‘ashish’, timeDetails: [{ startTime: ’10:00am’, endTime: ’6:00pm’, email: ‘ashish@gmail.com’, phone: ’93647626342’}, { startTime: ’11:00am’, endTime: ’7:00pm’, email: ‘ashish@gmail.com’, phone: ’93647626342’ }] } , 
     { id: 3, name: ‘sai’,  timeDetails: [{ startTime: ’7:00am’, endTime: ’3:00pm’, email: ‘sai@gmail.com’, phone: ’9746236547’}, { startTime: ’8:00am’, endTime: ’5:00pm’, email: ‘sai@gmail.com’, phone: ’9746236547’ }] }  ],   
    locationDetails : [{city: ‘Hyderabad’, country: ‘India’}, {city: ‘Chennai’, country: ‘India’}, {city: ‘Mumbai’, country: ‘India’} ]}
```

Looking for output like this. And also response is array of more objects that way (I mean response length is greater than 1). How can I have below output with multiple responses?

```
 data : Array<EmployeeDetails> = [];
    data = [ 
    { employee_id: 1, employee_name: ‘mounika’, employee_startDate: '01/01/2001’, employee_endDate: '02/02/2002’ , employee_startTime: ’10:00am’, endTime: ’5:00pm’, employee_email: ‘mounika@gmail.com’, employee_phone: ’9232323223’, employee_city: ‘Mumbai’, employee_country: ‘India’},  
    { employee_id: 2, employee_name: ‘ashish’, employee_startDate: '01/01/2001’, employee_endDate: '02/02/2002’ , employee_startTime: ’11:00am’, employee_endTime: ’7:00pm’, employee_email: ‘ashish@gmail.com’, employee_phone: ’93647626342’, employee_city: ‘Mumbai’, employee_country: ‘India’},
    { employee_id: 3, employee_name: ‘sai’, employee_startDate: '01/01/2001’, employee_endDate: '02/02/2002’ , employee_startTime: ’8:00am’, employee_endTime: ’5:00pm’, employee_email: ‘sai@gmail.com’, employee_phone: ’9746236547’,employee_city: ‘Mumbai’, employee_country: ‘India’}
    ]
```

Comment: What have you tried? This looks like a simple `for` loop over `queryResponse.personDetails`, or you can call `queryResponse.personDetails.map()`.

Comment: Can you please help me with code if you don't mind

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Try to transform your array in new with the help of Array.prototype.map()

```js
var data = queryResponse.personDetails.map(info => {
  return {employee_id: info.id, employee_name: info.name}
});
```

And you can transform other keys like that.

If you want to add Countries and cities you should use the second arguement in map "id", example:

```js
var data = queryResponse.personDetails.map((info, id) => ({
      employee_id: info.id, 
      employee_name: info.name, 
      employee_city: queryResponse.locationDetails[id].city,       
      employee_country: queryResponse.locationDetails[id].country
    })
 );
```

Comment: I have implemented one method, its going well. But I cannot do for response which has many objects.